# How can i redict ip which are out of range ip

Tags: ip, range, out

My question is how can i redirect ip out of a range of ip. 
I have a code that could redirect to url in range but i need to do opposite - redirect ip`s out of range.
Something similar to that:

```
$location = 'http://www.google.com/';

$range_low = ip2long("80.87.206.35");
$range_high = ip2long("80.87.206.38");

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($ip <= $range_low && $ip => $range_high) {
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: '.$location);  
}

else {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
$location = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$location2 = file_get_contents('http://www.ya.ru');

$range_low = ip2long("128.140.172.0");
$range_high = ip2long("128.140.175.255");

$range_low2 = ip2long("94.100.184.0");
$range_high2 = ip2long("94.100.191.255");

$range_low3 = ip2long("94.100.176.0");
$range_high3 = ip2long("94.100.183.255");

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


if (($ip < $range_low or $ip > $range_high) ^ ($ip < $range_low2 or $ip > $range_high2) ^ ($ip < $range_low3 or $ip > $range_high3)) {
echo $location;  // out of ip range

} else {
echo $location2; // in ip range
```